# Is it OK to use multiple inheritance if one parent class is an interface?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

[image]

Is it OK to use multiple inheritance if one parent class is an interface (only contains pure virtual functions with virtual destructor)?

I want to expose only interface part (yellow class in the picture) to increase compile speed. Green part is implementation part. But CPet should inherit from CAnimal(is-a relation) and IPet(implement), there are "Diamond of Death" :(

Interface classes (in yellow) only have pure virtual functions and virtual destruction, so when I create CDog, CCat through factory class, there are no problem like ambiguity. CDog has two vtables (from IDog and CPet) but in the virtual function tables, the points indicate same function (CDog member functions).

There's no compile error, no running error... but I'm worry about this hierarchy.
Is it OK or are there any problems?

PS : I don't want to use 'virtual inheritance' because if I use that, I can't look into class member variable through watch view.(I guess it is because virtual inheritance link to parent class like linked-list.)

Environment : Visual Studio C++ 2008 or over.

Comment: "I don't want to use 'virtual inheritance' because if I use that, I can't look into class member variable through watch view." Assuming this is true (I haven't verified it), maybe you should use a better debugger. You shouldn't avoid language features just because of the properties of your debugging environment. That's like not using `std::vector` just because it makes looking at an array slightly more difficult.

Comment: Only `Pets` can `Eat`?  Poor starving wild animals :-(

Comment: "I can't look into class member variable through watch view." — I can (VC++2010X).

Comment: "I want to expose only interface part (yellow class in the picture) to increase compile speed. " don't u use precompiled headers?

Comment: I should try to test at VS2010.. and other advices... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the description above, you should not be able instantiate an instance of `CPet` because the pure virtual function `IAnimal::isAlive()` is undefined in the `IPet` vtable.

```
struct IAnimal {
    virtual ~IAnimal() {}
    virtual void isAlive() = 0;
};

struct IPet : public IAnimal {
};

struct CAnimal : public IAnimal {
    virtual void isAlive() {
    }
};

struct CPet : public CAnimal, public IPet {
};

int main(void) {
    CPet cp;
}
```

Produces the following when compiled with Visual C++ 2008 & 2010:

```
animal.cpp(18) : error C2259: 'CPet' : cannot instantiate abstract class
    due to following members:
    'void IAnimal::isAlive(void)' : is abstract
    mytest.cpp(5) : see declaration of 'IAnimal::isAlive'
```

GCC produces a similiar warning:

```
animal.cpp: In function 'int main()':
animal.cpp:18:7: error: cannot declare variable 'cp' to be of abstract type 'CPet'
animal.cpp:14:8: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'CPet':
animal.cpp:3:15: note:  virtual void IAnimal::isAlive()
```

Comment: Everything works fine if virtual inheritance is used.  Thus DRH's answer points out that virtual inheritance is required to make this hierarchy work as one would expect.  See, e.g. http://ideone.com/moCCp

Comment: Thanks. As Managu says "everything works fine if virtual inheritance is used". But my compiler(Visual Studio 2008) says 'warning C4250: 'CPet' : inherits 'CAnimal::CAnimal::isAlive' via dominance' :(

Comment: Correct, you can read more about that warning (and how to silence it) here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b3sy7ae.aspx.